# load data local file into mysql from python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to load data from a file into a table in my mysql server using the

```
load data local infile '<filename>' into table <tablename>
```

command but it gives the error 1148.
I understand this is due to some security issues and that I have to enable local-infile 
option to get this command to execute.

But since I am trying to execute this through python, I am not sure how can I enable this option.

Additional Info: I am using mysqldb import for python

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after a bit of googling.

A couple of answers point towards the fact that I can edit

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

and add
    local-infile=0
in the fie

But sometimes(not sure why) python won't pick up the settings from the file.

You can pass the argument:

```
read_default_file="/etc/mysql/my.cnf"
```

while creating the connection to the database, as follows

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='passwd',db='db',charset = "utf8", use_unicode = True,read_default_file="/etc/mysql/my.cnf")
```